# PHP version compatibility issue for multiple projects

Tags: php, ampps

I have 2 php projects both are running on different php version. 
i.e.
1. http://website_1 --> **PHP5.3**
2.http://website_2 --> PHP5.6 on same machine i am running **ampps 3.7.**

Does ampps will support both the versions of php at the same time, so that i can run both my projects without having the overhead of changing version every time running the project.

Comment: **Danger**: 5.3 hasn't been supported for security fixes since 2014. **Do not use it**. 5.6 is still getting security fixes but isn't under active support. You should consider upgrading soon.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: You can choose the PHP version, BUT not two at the same time.  Both your sites use old version, migrating to a single recent version would be the best.

Comment: My question is is it possible to use two versions of PHP at the same time.